# How to sort a dataframe by multiple column(s), each column in a different direction?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to order in ASC order on one column and in DESC order on the second column. Suppose I have this data:

```
names <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b")
values <- c(4,1,1,2,4)
smallData <- data.frame(name = names, value = values)
smallData
  name value
2    a     1
3    b     1
4    b     2
1    a     4
5    b     4
```

I know I can order `smallData` like:

```
smallData[order(smallData$name),]
smallData[order(smallData$name, decreasing = T),]
smallData[order(smallData$name, smallData$value),]
```

But how I can order by name ASC and then by value DESC? The output should look like:

```
  name value
1    a     4
2    a     1
5    b     4
4    b     2
3    b     1
```

NOTE: Would prefer a base R implementation but curious to see how this can be done

Comment: Do you need `smallData %>% arrange(desc(name), value)`

Comment: @akrun Is this from some package?

Comment: it is from `dplyr`

Comment: I would prefer a base R solution as I am using a very old version of R (for reasons outside of the scope of this discussion) which `dplyr` won't run on but feel free to add as an answer.

Comment: Ok, looks like these ordering should come sequentially and without the previous one affecting it (based on your try)

Comment: Your sample data does not give enough variability to show the different sort order.

Comment: If there are `n` columns and also have different parameter arguments for `order`, a possible option (still uses `purrr`) would be `f1 <- list(partial(order, decreasing = TRUE), order);
for(i in seq_along(smallData)) smallData <- smallData[lift(compose)(f1[[i]])(smallData[[i]]),]`  Note that what you want is sequential

Comment: Can you please show the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set the values of `value` to negative to reverse that order:

```
smallData[order(smallData$name, -smallData$value),]
```

or with `rank`, which would also work with character variables:

```
smallData[order(smallData$name, -rank(smallData$value)),]
```

**Output:**

```
  name value
1    a     4
2    a     1
5    b     4
4    b     2
3    b     1
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. You guys rock!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but you can user `order` in this way :

```
names <- c("paul", "mark", "dave", "will", "john")
values <- c(1,4,1,2,1)
smallData <- data.frame(name = names, value = values)

index <- order(smallData$name)
smallData <- smallData[index,]

index <- order(smallData$value)
smallData <- smallData[index,]
```

Which outputs :

> ```
> > smallData
>   name value
> 3 dave     1
> 5 john     1
> 1 paul     1
> 4 will     2
> 2 mark     4
> ```